# Notepad++ deleting string in multiple files

Tags: lua, notepad++

I'm trying to removing a specific line from many files I'm working on with Notepad++.

For example i've a lines:
1 file:

```
<mana now="110" max="110" manaGain="6" manaTicks="500" type="3"/>
```

2 file:

```
<mana now="100" max="100" manaGain="11" manaTicks="500"/>
```

As you can see, there are different values. I'd like to remove this string  from all files. Can i do it with Notepad++, especially if each file has a different value?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Notepad++ and RegEx. You maybe warned - please make a **backup copy** of all files first.

I assume your files all have the extension *.xml and reside in folder e.g. **D:\_working**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>

  <mana now="110" max="110" manaGain="6" manaTicks="500" type="3"/>

</bookstore>
```

- First open **one** of the files in your working directory by Notepad++
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Go to the *Find in Files* tab
- Find what:`<mana now="[0-9]{1,}" max="[0-9]{1,}" manaGain="[0-9]{1,}" manaTicks="[0-9]{1,}".+`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- Filters: *.xml
- Directory: e.g. D:\_working
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>
- Click on <kbd>OK</kbd> when you're really sure.

You may want to refine the RegEx for your needs. Short explanation:

- `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- `{1,}` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
- `.+` matches any character (except for line terminators)

This is resulting in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>



</bookstore>
```

Comment: `[0-9]{1,}` is better written `\d+`. You assume that attributes are always in same order